# Algorithm Question relating "Code Bat" question

Tags: java, logic

https://codingbat.com/prob/p183562

We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return true if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks. This is a little harder than it looks and can be done without any loops. See also: Introduction to MakeBricks

makeBricks(3, 1, 8) → true
makeBricks(3, 1, 9) → false
makeBricks(3, 2, 10) → true

```
    public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if((small + (big * 5)) < goal){
    return false;
  }
  if((small >= (goal % 5)) && goal % 5 >= big) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And others like it Do not work whereas....

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if((small + (big * 5)) < goal){
    return false;
  }
  if((small >= (goal % 5))) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Does. 
Wouldn't we have to check if be have enough big? I am very confused.

Comment: Avoid put the question just as a link

Comment: checking `(goal <= big*5 + small) && (small >= goal % 5)` will be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough small bricks, then the `small + (big * 5)) < goal)` condition will already test if you have enough big bricks.

Adding `goal % 5 >= big` won't work because you don't always need the big bricks. If you needed 10 inches, then you can use 2 big bricks, or 10 small bricks, or 1 big brick and 5 small bricks.

Comment: do you think  checking only `small + (big * 5)) < goal)` will work? small and big can be any positive integer. example `makeBricks(3, 2, 9`

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find the implementation of the solution (or one of the solutions maybe).

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {

  int reqBig = goal / 5; // how many big bricks can be used to reach goal

  if (reqBig <= big) 
  {
    if (goal % 5 <= small) // check if you have the required small bricks to reach goal
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    int reqSmall = goal - big*5; // how many small bricks required to reach goal

    if (reqSmall <= small)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: checking `(goal  <= big*5 + small) && (small >= goal % 5)` will be enough

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's why I said it can be one of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this should check the bricks

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {

  if ( (goal  <= big*5 + small) && (small >= goal % 5)) {    
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be the compacted version of what I did right?